# shortener author name and multiple citation in APA style citation

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, apacite

I have two question with my APA citation style:

1. In in-text citation, I try to write two citation side by side like this:

> First page of results have been considered by most of the users (Bailey et al. 2016; Lam 2016).

Bu I am getting this:

> First page of results have been considered by most of the users (Bailey, Kapitanios, & Pesaran, 2016) (Lam, 2016)

This is my latex text:

`First page of results have been considered by most of the users \cite{bailey2016exponent} \cite{lam2016nonparametric}.`

2. My citation is show full name of authors like  `Bailey, Kapitanios, & Pesaran, 2016` I want it to show just first name of author like `Bailey et al. 2016`

And this is my .bib

```
    @article{bailey2016exponent,
      title={Exponent of Cross-Sectional Dependence: Estimation and 
      Inference},
      author={Bailey, Natalia and Kapetanios, George and Pesaran, M Hashem},
      journal={Journal of Applied Econometrics},
      volume={31},
      number={6},
      pages={929--960},
      year={2016},
      publisher={Wiley Online Library}
      }

      @article{lam2016nonparametric,
      title={Nonparametric eigenvalue-regularized precision or covariance matrix estimator},
      author={Lam, Clifford},
      journal={The Annals of Statistics},
      volume={44},
      number={3},
      pages={928--953},
      year={2016},
      publisher={Institute of Mathematical Statistics}
```

And this is my .tex file:

```
     \documentclass[11pt]{article}
     \usepackage{apacite}
     \begin{document}
     \title{Sample Document}
     \author{ABC ABC}
     \date{Today}
     \maketitle

     First page of results have been considered by most of the users 
     \cite{bailey2016exponent} \cite{lam2016nonparametric}. 

     \bibliographystyle{apacite}
     \bibliography{GoScholarRef}
     \end{document}
```

How can I fix these two problem ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you consider using biblatex-apa?

Comment: I don't know the details of `[style=apa]` for biblatex, but with biblatex,  you can use the keys `maxcitenames=`, `mincitenames=`, independently of `maxbibnames=` and `minbibnames=`. You'll see the details in the documentation.

Comment: Are you actually using the `apacite` package? Can you post a small document that shows what you're doing. The `.bib` items are  helpful but we also need to see a document.

Comment: Ok, I will post it, tanks for your advice

Comment: If you put the cite keys in the same `\cite` command they will be put together in the same set of parentheses. The full list of authors (up to 5) is required by the APA for the first mention of a work; after that it will be abbreviated automatically.  This is built into the `.bst` file and is not easy to change at all.  If you don't need actual APA conforming style you might be better off using `biblatex` with `authoryear` style and modifying that to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so can I edit 'biblatex' and 'authoryear' to looks like APA style as my example above ?

Comment: The standard `authoryear` callout style pretty much looks like that. There may be some tweaks needed to the bibliography itself depending in your requirements.  See [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806).

Comment: I really suggest using the `biblatex-apa` package, together with `biber`, it is up to date, if you need to confirm to APA.

Comment: Can you please give an example how to apply it or give me a referance link to go with it ?